# throttle function and event-delegation

Tags: javascript, event-delegation, throttling

My Problem, i want to debounce function calls, but related to the scope the function is called.

In my example, i look for event-delegated clicks and debounce the clicks.

This works, but the debouncing is not element-specific!

http://jsbin.com/itapuf/2/edit

Is there a elegant way?

---

**edit:**
To be more specific (my english is not the best)

I want to replace this code:

```
$('#blue').on('click',function(id){
    addBeep('trigger');
}.throttle(300) );

$('#green').on('click',function(id){
    addBeep('trigger');
}.throttle(300) );
```

By this one (event delegated):

```
$('#btns').on('click','button', function(id){
    addBeep('trigger');
}.throttle(300) );
```

But if i do that, latest clicks on specific elements can be lost.

I need something like:

```
$('#btns').on('click','button', function(id){
    addBeep('trigger');
}.throttle(300, {bindToScopt:true} ) );
```

But how to change the throttle function to work like this?

Or is there a better solution for this Problem?

Comment: Can you introduce a library?  I suggest underscorejs.  It has a debouncer and other useful function delegation wrappers.

Comment: Uh, that would be complicated. Why do you need event delegation? I'd really recommend to use different functions, but set them up in a loop or so.

Comment: Ok, i have a solution!
If the scope changes, the functions triggers immediately.

http://q1-code.info.shwups-cms.ch/de/libraries/q1/debounce-throttle-functions/?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you might want to add the following at proper place

```
 e.stopPropagation()
```

This stops all propagation of the event in the bubbling phase. For a complete cross-browser experience do

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Please do read the complete post about [Event Handling at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)